# Angular-Keycloak is not adding the bearer token by default to my http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I'm trying to implement keycloak-angular but I'm not able to add the bearer token by default to my http requests.

"keycloak-angular": "9.1.0"
"keycloak-js": "16.0.0"
"Angular": "13.0.2"

```
    function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return async () =>
   await keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8443/auth',
        realm: '*****',
        clientId: '****',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerExcludedUrls: [],
      bearerPrefix:'Bearer '
    });
}



 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it' },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak, 
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to add custom headers at each api call.
Create your interceptor, and add it to AppModule

```
providers: [
 {
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: ApiInterceptor,
   multi: true,
 }
],
```

Implement the intercept function :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer #YOUR_TOKEN_HERE#`
    }
  });

  return next.handle(request);
}
```

Comment: It was missing to add
 { 
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
      multi: true 
  }
In my sharedModule because I had it inside HttpClientModule

Answer (score 1):

In my case the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) was not used to do the requests.

Instead **[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) has been used directly** and that is not intercepted by angular.

So if you have the HttpInterceptor in place and it does not work, be sure HttpClient is used to do the requests.

I changed `fetch(...)` to `http.get(...)` and it worked